# Can you change the Silverlight download indicator graphic?

Tags: silverlight

When a Silverlight application is downloading you get the percentage text and the blue dots moving around it as a progress indicator. Is it possible to modify this to have a custom progress indicator instead? It would be nice to have something matching the theme of the application that will run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can designate a loose xaml file from your website app to be displayed using the [SplashScreenSource property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.silverlightcontrols.silverlight.splashscreensource(VS.95).aspx) of the [asp:silverlight webcontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.silverlightcontrols.silverlight(VS.95).aspx) (or splashScreenSouce param for the  html <object> tag.) while the main xap source is being downloaded.